# Derivative of a minimum

Tags: derivatives, convex-optimization, implicit-differentiation

The expression, $e=\left(x(t,w)-c_x\right){}^2+\left(y(t,w)-c_y\right){}^2$, has a local minimum with respect to $t$ at some $t_0(w)$. Now what does $t_0'(w)$ look like?!

$x,y\in C^2$ with respect to both $t$ and $w$. Moreover for all $w$, $e$ is strictly convex with respect to $t$ at $t_0(w)$. Do you have any advice?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you've found the formula for $t_0'(w)$; are you asking for information about its curvature/shape? I don't think you can say much in particular about it.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant I mean what is that formula. I haven't found it, because the problem is I really have no idea how to derive it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use the notation where a $t$ or $w$ subscript represents partial differentiation on that variable; *e.g.*, $x_{tw}\triangleq \partial^2 x(t,w) / \partial t\partial w$.

In order for $t$ to be the local minimum for fixed $w$, you must have
$$2(x-c_x)x_t+2(y-c_y)y_t=0$$
This equation is satisfied for all $t_0(w)$. Differentiating implicitly I get
$$2 x_t ( x_t dt + x_w dw ) + 2(x-c_x) (x_{tt} dt + x_{tw} dw)+
  2 y_t ( y_t dt + y_w dw ) + 2(y-c_y) (y_{tt} dt + y_{tw} dw)=0$$
or
$$\frac{dt}{dw} =
 - \frac{ x_tx_w + (x-c_x)x_{tw} + y_ty_w + (y-c_y)y_{tw} }{ x_t^2 + (x-c_x)x_{tt} + y_t^2 + (y-c_y)y_{tt} }$$
I'm not sure this can be simplified significantly. Note that this remains an implicitly definied function, because it depends on both $t$ and $w$.

Comment: The fraction contains no symbols between which there is any relation, so I think this is actually simplified.